# Best practice for including vender assets in Rails 4 Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I can't find a good resource for explaining how to include a more complicated 3rd party package that includes js, css, and other types of assets within the same plugin.  For example, the [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) plugin has a lot of different assets spread out in multiple folders.  I have put it in the `vendor/assets/plupload/` folder and then require the tree in my manifest file, but then it refers to other other files with a relative pathname that works in development, but the path changes in production.  I can then change the references to use `asset_path`, but then I am modifying the vendor code which just seems wrong.

I know there is a gem out there for the plupload library, I am just using it as a case study to try and understand the best practice for including a more complicated 3rd party library than what the Rails Guides show.

Thanks!

Comment: The best practice is to use the gem.

Comment: Thanks diego, but not every library has a gem.  And many times (plupload included) the gem is outdated.

Comment: It's very easy to make gems. Using bundler you can run "bundle gem gem_name" and it will generate a skeleton gem directory where you can copy in your 3rd party lib files. When you're ready to use it, add it to your gem file with "gem 'gem_name', path: '/path/to/gem/dir'".

Comment: You might give https://rails-assets.org a try.  Bower -> Gem

Answer (score 0):

You can place the contents related to any plugin or library in a single folder public folder. This will make all your assets available and there should not be any issue.